# Array map into string with line break - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reactjs

I have a function which I need to return a string with line breaks, or divs that will render properly

```
export const showPeople = (peopleArray = []) => {
  let peopleString = peopleArray ? peopleArray.map((people) => {
    <div>
      `${people.name && people.name},
      ${people.last_name && people.last_name}`
    </div>
  }).join('') : ''
  return peopleString
}
```

I tried with divs, without divs, with return without return, and without join and i get [Object] for each person, in this particular case an empty string

I have seen similar questions but was not able to solve my problem

Comment: Like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/y2v5nr933z

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is to reduce a list of items to a single string that is rendered as a multi-line string, then you can use the `white-space:pre-wrap;` CSS rule to achieve this:

```
body {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Once you've done that you should be able to render a multiple line string with line breaks on `\n` characters, as follows:

```
export const showPeople = (peopleArray = []) => {

  let peopleString = peopleArray ? peopleArray.map((people) => (
      `${people.name ? people.name : ''} ${people.last_name ? people.last_name : ''}`
  })
  .join('\n') : ''

  return peopleString
}
```

[I've posted a working version here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6wl335k443) for you to see also

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want the line break between the different people, not between name and last name

Comment: @user3808307 ah I understand , just updated answer - does this help you?

Comment: @user3808307 ok , I've just posted an update - does this work for you?

Comment: No, I tried that, thanks. I've solved it by doing the map in the render now, None of the solutions work

Answer (score 3):

```
export const showPeople = (peopleArray = []) => {
  let peopleString = peopleArray ? peopleArray.map(people => 
  `<div>
      ${people.name}, ${people.last_name}
    </div>`
  ).join('') : ''
  return peopleString
}
```

---

```js
var peoples = [{name: 'Jhon', last_name: 'Doe'},{name: 'Mario', last_name: 'Peach'}]

var peopleString = peoples.map(people => 
  `<div>
    ${people.name}, ${people.last_name}
  </div>`
).join('')

console.log(peopleString)

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = peopleString
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Luis That doesn't work, I get weird characters instead of the <div>, it's inward and outward arrows something similar to this <- div -> but with longer lines

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that the OP uses React.

Answer (score 3):

You dont want to return a string you want to return an array of  elements:

```
let peopleString = peopleArray.map((people) => (
  <div>
   {people.name || ""},
   {people.last_name || ""}
  </div>
));
return peopleString
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not doing string concatenation with variables. You need to remove **Template Strings** inside your divs.

Comment: `${people.name && people.name}` is string concatenation with variables.

Comment: I am also concatenating with a comma between name and last name

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you are **not returning anything** in that map function:

`(people) => { ...string here... }`

I would suggest, simply:

`(people) => ( ...string here... )`

or:

`(people) => { return ...string here... }`

---

Another issue might be that what you seem to intend to return in the map function is NOT a string, and probably(?) should be; it's hard to say without seeing the function in context.

Answer (score 1):

So if you specifically want to use the HTML Line Break element to separate the strings you can use this.

```js
import { Fragment, ReactNode } from "react";

const separateWithLineBreaks = (strings: string[]): ReactNode => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {strings.map((str, index) => (
        <Fragment key={index}>
          {str}
          {index < strings.length - 1 && <br />}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```